# How to find element locator when dropdown closes on click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to select a value from the dropdown using the Selenium web driver.

I automated many dropdowns but this time I got stuck with a unique dropdown. When I click on the dropdown the values are displayed and when right-clicking a dropdown value to inspect the element or any click made on the browser the dropdown closes. The code also changes when values are displayed and not displayed. There is no "li" list in the HTML code.

After doing a google search I found a similar dropdown at xe.com. When I click on currency dropdown all the currencies are displayed but when I try to find the locator of currency the dropdown disappears.

Is there a way to automate this kind of dropdown? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to inspect the dropdown from xe.com with this workaround:

1. Right-click and inspect (DevTools opens)
2. Right-click > break on > subtree modifications
3. Go back to the page and click the dropdown and the DevTools switches to debug-mode
4. Go to "Source" tab of DevTools and either press "Resume script execution" or press the "F8" keyboard button

After playing around a bit, you should be able to get the page HTML "frozen" at the right moment. Then just go to the "Console" tab of DevTools and find the needed element.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had to follow the above steps multiple times to make it stay

Comment: Glad you made it.